# How do I format this table into being better looking?

Tags: tabularx

I have made this table but it's not really good looking. How could I improve it? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}     
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ | m{4em} | m{1.3cm}| m{1.3cm} | m{1cm} | } 
        \hline & Gedopt & Nicht . &\\
        \hline
        Test zeigt positiv & $\frac{0,999}{600}$ & $\frac{1,2}{600}$ & $\frac{2.199}{600}$  \\ 
        \hline
        Test zeigt negativ & $\frac{0,001}{600}$ & $\frac{597,8}{600}$  & $\frac{597,8}{600}$\\ 
        \hline
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ & $\frac{1}{600}$ & $\frac{599}{600}$ & \\ 
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `booktabs` package, and get rid of the vertical lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}     
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{m{4em}m{1.3cm}m{1.3cm}m{1cm}} 
        \toprule & Gedopt & Nicht . &\\
        \midrule
        Test zeigt positiv & $\frac{0,999}{600}$ & $\frac{1,2}{600}$ & $\frac{2.199}{600}$  \\ 
        \midrule
        Test zeigt negativ & $\frac{0,001}{600}$ & $\frac{597,8}{600}$  & $\frac{597,8}{600}$\\ 
        \midrule
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ & $\frac{1}{600}$ & $\frac{599}{600}$ & \\ 
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image: table test]

## Edit

@Zarko's answer is better than mine.

Comment: however, op more liked your answer than mine :-(

Answer (score 3):

maybe like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l *{3}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}} }
    \toprule
                    & \text{Gedopt}     & \text{Nicht}      &\\
    \midrule
Test zeigt positiv  & \frac{0,999}{600} & \frac{1,2}{600}   & \frac{2.199}{600}\\
Test zeigt negativ  & \frac{0,001}{600} & \frac{597,8}{600} & \frac{597,8}{600}\\
                    & \frac{1}{600}     & \frac{599}{600}   & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Better looking" is a very subjective and wide concept. Of course, with `booktabs` and without vertical, but beside this you can also try  another strategies, as use a decimal alignment, or change the fraction style, or redesign the table:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicefrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l *{3}{S}}
    \toprule
                    & \text{Gedopt}     & \text{Nicht}      &\\
    \midrule
Test zeigt positiv  & \nicefrac{0,999}{600} & \nicefrac{1,2}{600}   & \nicefrac{2.199}{600}\\
Test zeigt negativ  & \nicefrac{0,001}{600} & \nicefrac{597,8}{600} & \nicefrac{597,8}{600}\\
                    & \nicefrac{1}{600}     & \nicefrac{599}{600}   & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ l *{3}{S} }
    \toprule
Test zeigt ($\times600$) & \text{Gedopt}     & \text{Nicht}      &  \\
    \midrule
Positiv  & 0,999 & 1,2   & 2.199\\
Negativ  & 0,001 & 597,8 & 597,8\\
                    & 1     & 599   & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```